# Why does my update model operation cause duplicates in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've tried different approaches but my models are being duplicated on every update.

I pass a person object from my view to the controller method via a HTTP POST operation and then call the `.Update(...)` method.

My view is:

```
@model Falcon.Models.Person

<h2>User @Model.FullName</h2>
<div>
    <form method="post" class=container>
    <section>
        <h4>General information</h4>
    
    <div class=row>
    <div class=col-25><label asp-for=Surname></label></div>
    <div class=col-75><input asp-for=Surname type="text"/></div>
    </div>  
     <div class=row>
    <div class=col-25><label asp-for=Name></label></div>
    <div class=col-75><input asp-for=Name type="text"/></div>
    </div>  
     ......
    <div class=row> 
        <div class=col-25><label asp-for=Email></label> </div>
        <div class=col-75><input asp-for=Email type="email" /></div>
    </div>         
</section>

<input type="submit" value="Submit changes" asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Person"/>     
</form>
```

My `PersonController`'s action is:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit (Person person)
    {
        db.Persons.Update(person);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();           
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Why are my objects being duplicated on every update operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mapping a `Person` model (`@model Falcon.Models.Person`) which will be determined unique by a primary key - let's say `Person.Id`.

Since you're not binding *something* in your UI to your ID, ASP.NET is generating a *new* ID every time, meaning it's being recognised as a new person on every "update".

Make it a hidden field so ASP.NET can pass the existing `Id` value through, and knows it is an update operation & not a creation.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add hidden field for  a primary key - Person.Id. Without this entity framework can decide that it is a new object

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
```